# Float left and right on same line but treat differently when spills onto second line

Tags: html, css

Take the following simple example:

https://jsfiddle.net/ds9b1gyr/

with HTML as follows:

```html
<span style="float:left;">| this is a first part |</span>
<span style="float:right;">| this is a second part |</span>
```

In the jsfiddle, slide the vertical separator bar to the right, and the left part approaches the right part, remaining on the same line.  This is the effect I want, so far.

But when the left and right parts meet, so that content has to spill over to the next line, I don't want the *whole* second part to drop to the second line in one go.  What I want is for as much content in the second part as possible to *remain on the first line*, with the second line "spill" either being centred, or floating left, or floating right (depending on a user preference).

Is this possible with CSS?

EDIT to show example of the effect I am after:

example when not yet spilled over to next line:

[image]

example when spilled over to next line:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, I would recommend still preparing the content for responsive, but this is one way you can achieve it:

```css
 .text-wrap {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

```html
<div class="text-wrap">
 <span>| this is a first part this is a first part this is a first part this is a first part |</span>
 <span>| this is a second part this is a second part this is a second part this is a second part this is a second part |</span>
</div>
```

**Things to note:** The nowrap and the text wrap properties

### Edit

Updated answer according to feedback...

```css
.text-wrap {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
 .span-one {
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
 }
 .span-two {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: right;
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
 .text-wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
  .text-wrap span {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
  }
   .text-wrap span + span {
    margin-top: 20px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-wrap">
 <span class="span-one">| this is a first part this is a first part this is a first part this is a first part |</span>
 <span class="span-two">| this is a second part this is a second part this is a second part this is a second part this is a second part |</span>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you ensure that the first part does not spill onto a second line?  When there is a long second part (like this: https://jsfiddle.net/d13uzp2x/), I'd like the second part to break and spill over, not the first part (it should remain unbroken on the first line).

Comment: I will update my answer when I get back to my computer in the morning. I will need to test it.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully this is what you mean? I added some media queries to get you started on the responsiveness as this will be tricky to scale down to mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS Flex to for your requirement.

**Update as on 16/10/2019:**
I am not sure if css alone can help you achieve what you ask. But with the help of jQuery, I got what you've asked.
Hope this helps. :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var addedContent;
var contentOneWidth=$("#span1").width()+10;
var actedWindowWidth;
 $(window).resize(function(){
    var spanTwoLeftDist=$("#span2").offset().left;
    if(spanTwoLeftDist<=contentOneWidth){
     if(!addedContent){
        addedContent=$("#span2").html();
        $("#span1").html($("#span1").html()+addedContent);
        $('#result').text("inside");
        $("#span2").empty();
        $("#span1").css("flex-shrink","");
        actedWindowWidth=$(window).width();
      }
    }
    else if(actedWindowWidth && $(window).width()>actedWindowWidth){
     if(addedContent){
       $("#span2").html(addedContent);
        $("#span1").html($("#span1").html().replace(addedContent,""));
        $("#span1").css("flex-shrink","0");
        addedContent=null;
        actedWindowWidth=null;
      }
    }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;justify-content: space-between;">
      <span style="flex-shrink: 0" id="span1">| this is a first part |</span>
      <span id="span2">| this is a second part this is a second part this is a second part this is a second part |</span>
     
</div>
```

**Update:**

Use *flex-shrink:0* on the element you don't want to shrink.
I have updated my code accordingly.

**Note:** 
`style="flex-basis: 200px"` has been used to specify the initial width of the second span element. I provided it to display the right align effect. You may discard it as per your preference.

Refer CSS FlexBox for more https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Hope it helps you now. :)

```html
<!--Updated answer-->
    <div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;justify-content: space-between;">
      <span style="flex-shrink: 0">| this is a first part |</span>
      <span style="flex-basis: 200px">| this is a second part this is a second part this is a second part this is a second part |</span>
    </div>

<!--Old answer-->

    <div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;justify-content: space-between;">
      <span>| this is a first part |</span><span>| this is a second part |</span> 
    </div>
```

In this, the text will not spill to the next line at once.

Comment: How do you ensure that the first part does not spill onto a second line?  When there is a long second part (like this: https://jsfiddle.net/d13uzp2x/), I'd like the second part to break and spill over, not the first part (it should remain unbroken on the first line).

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer.  This is almost what I want, but the second part remains as a block.  Is it possible for the second part to float left on the second line (when it spills over) under the first part... I've added an example of what I mean to the original question.  I'm guessing that this is starting to go beyond what is possible with CSS.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this to your CSS:

```
span {
  width: 50%;
}
span:last-child {
  text-align:right;
}
```